# Not able to access JQuery data-* attribute value of a button control despite rendering the value in browser DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am encountering a very strange problem.

I can see in the browser this:

```
<button type="button" redirect-url="/PP/818003/ABC/Index" data-xyz="single" data-url="/PP/818003/PatientForms/RequiredFormFields?patientId=0&amp;appointmentId=0" id="btnConsentFormDecline+382" class="btn btn-primary">Decline</button>
```

But when I am trying to access the `data-xyz` attribute, I am getting undefined!
I am trying to access using:

```
$("#btnConsentFormDecline+382").attr("data-xyz")
```

I have been breaking my head over this for the last 2 hours and it might be something very simple.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The correct usage is `var xyz = $("#btnConsentFormDecline+382").data("xyz");`

Comment: You really have a `+` in the id? weird.

Comment: The `+` sign will be interpreted as a jquery selector. It will attempt to find an `<xyz>` element (there is not such element) that immediatly follows an element with `id="btnConsentFormDecline"`

Comment: $("#btnConsentFormDecline+382").data("xyz") is giving undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove + from id and use `data()` instead `attr`

[jQuery data() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_data.asp)

with [plus](http://jsfiddle.net/ab74mzLg/1/) + it will still give you `undefined` even if you use `data()`

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="btnConsentFormDecline382" redirect-url="/PP/818003/ABC/Index" data-xyz="single" data-url="/PP/818003/PatientForms/RequiredFormFields?patientId=0&amp;appointmentId=0" class="btn btn-primary">Decline</button>
```

JS

```
$("#btnConsentFormDecline382").data("xyz");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab74mzLg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special character in your selector and you should be using data()

```js
console.log($("#btnConsentFormDecline\\+382").data("xyz"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" redirect-url="/PP/818003/ABC/Index" data-xyz="single" data-url="/PP/818003/PatientForms/RequiredFormFields?patientId=0&amp;appointmentId=0" id="btnConsentFormDecline+382" class="btn btn-primary">Decline</button>
```

Comment: Thank You!I could not accept both as solution,but your approach is also appretiated!